# Conditional import of rows in text files

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a code here where in I import the contents of a text file and do some plotting. My requirement is that, I want to import only those rows of data by giving a condition. After doing some calculations on the imported data, I want to import the rest of rows remaining in the text file and do further calculations. After this process is done, I want to combine the two calculations into two arrays respectively.

This is the sample code that I have. I have also uploaded the text file into dropbox.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate  import RectBivariateSpline
import numdifftools as nd
plt.ioff()

data5= np.loadtxt('textfile',skiprows=1,unpack = True).T
ts3 = data5[:,1] ## Condition based on this data
fillend= 37900   ## Read rows only till this value
ft3 = data5[:,0]
t3 = data5[:,2]
Ek3 = data5[:,13]
ek3 = data5[:,14]
eko3 = data5[:,15]
Eko3 = data5[:,16]

## Initially I want to read only all the rows until ts3=37900 with the row corresponding to fillend also included
## Until ts3 =37900, this is the calculation that I want to make

e2 = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(t2,Ek2,k=5) ## Here length of Ek2 and t2 should be equal to 378)

df2 =nd.Derivative(e2,method='central',n=1,order=2,full_output=False)
e2 = (1-df2(t2))
df2 = df2(t2)

## Beyond ts3 = 37900, i.e from 38000 onwards, this is the calculation that I want to make
df2 =nd.Derivative(e2,method='central',n=1,order=2,full_output=False)
e2 = (-df2(t2))
df2 = df2(t2)

## At the end of the operation, I want to have only two arrays e2 and df2 with all the values calculated
```

[Sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8l6uijhabhu1fc7/ddn180nonkeh.txt?dl=0)

Comment: I can't tell, at a glance, what in this code is working and what is just desired, and/or whether there are errors.  If this is working, what is the question?

Comment: @hpaulj My objective is to import all the rows till ts3 = 37900 including. Then I want to do some calculations as shown above. After this calculation is completed, I want to import the rest of the rows and do the second calculation. In the code, this is not implemented. It is just going to import all the rows and do the calculations.

Comment: `loadtxt` reads the file line by line, collecting the results in a list.  You can perform the same sort of read.  Also `loadtxt` accepts input from any code that feeds it lines.  Thus your file reader can read the file line by line, and pass them on to `loadtxt`, or quit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of loading txt (lines) in two blocks, based on a value in the lines.  I'm simulating a file with a list of strings. `foo` is a generator function that returns the input in 2 blocks.

```
import numpy as np

t0 = '1, 2, 3, 4'
t1 = '4, 5, 6, 7'
txt=[t0,t0,t0,t1,t1,t1]

def foo(txt):
    lines = []
    while txt:
        l = txt.pop(0)
        if int(l.split(',')[1])<4: lines.append(l)
        else:
            yield lines
            break
    yield [l]+txt

for lines in foo(txt[:]):
    print(np.loadtxt(lines, delimiter=','))
```

The result is 2 arrays:

```
2033:~/mypy$ python stack36001473.py 
[[ 1.  2.  3.  4.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.  4.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.  4.]]
[[ 4.  5.  6.  7.]
 [ 4.  5.  6.  7.]
 [ 4.  5.  6.  7.]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think I might have confused on what I desire. I have a text file already generated. After importing the text file, I have assigned variables to different columns. After this, I want to import only rows till ts3 value = 37900. Please look at the attached text file to get a better idea.

Comment: If you turn your problem into one the size of my example, you might get more help.